# Generating a list of prime numbers using list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of all the prime numbers less than or equal to a given number. I did that successfully using for loops. I was trying to achieve the same using list comprehension using python. But my output has some unexpected values.

Here is my code..

```
pr=[2]
pr+=[i for i in xrange(3,num+1) if not [x for x in pr if i%x==0]]
```

where `num` is the number I had taken as input from user.

The output of the above code for

```
num=20 is this:  [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

I'm puzzled as to why 9 and 15 are there in the output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Variable `pr` is assigned the new value only AFTER the whole comprehension is executed. During execution, it does not change at all.

Comment: This kind of code would work in a dataflow-based language (where variables are kind of like spreadsheet cells), and could be made to work in a lazy-evaluation language, so it's not a bad idea… it just doesn't work in Python. You have to explicitly update `pr` one element at a time in a `for` statement (or do something horribly hacky which you shouldn't do so I won't explain it).

Comment: @abarnert *“or do something horribly hacky”* – Oops, I did… sorry :(

Comment: @poke: At least you didn't use `consume(map(pr.__iadd__, …))`. :)

Answer (score 5):

It simply doesn’t work that way. List comprehensions are evaluated separately, so you can imagine it like this:

```
pr = [2]
tmp = [i for i in xrange(3,num+1) if not [x for x in pr if i%x==0]]
pr += tmp
```

By the time `tmp` is evaluated, `pr` only contains `2`, so you only ever check if a number is divisible by 2 (i.e. if it’s even). That’s why you get all uneven numbers.

You simply can’t solve this nicely<sup>†</sup> using list comprehensions.

---

† Not nicely, but ugly and in a very hackish way, by abusing that you can call functions inside a list comprehension:

```
pr = [2]
[pr.append(i) for i in xrange(3,num+1) if not [x for x in pr if i%x==0]]
print(pr) # [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

This abuses list comprehensions and basically collects a `None` value for each prime number you add to `pr`. So it’s essentially like your normal for loop except that we unnecessarily collect `None` values in a list… so you should rather allow yourself to use a line break and just use a normal loop.

Answer (score 4):

Your list `pr` doesn't update until after your entire list comprehension is done. This means your list only contains 2, so every number dividable by 2 is not in the list (as you can see). You should update the list whenever you found a new prime number.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `pr += [...]` is evaluated approximately as this:

```
pr = [2]
tmp = [i for i in xrange(3,num+1) if not [x for x in pr if i%x==0]]
pr.extend(tmp)
```

So while `tmp` is generated, contents of `pr` remains the same (`[2]`).

I would go with function like this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def primes():
...     results = []
...     for i in itertools.count(2):
...         if all(i%x != 0 for x in results):
...             results.append(i)
...             yield i
...
# And then you can fetch first 10 primes
>>> list(itertools.islice(primes(), 10))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
# Or get primes smaller than X
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < 50, primes()))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

Note, that using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#all) is more efficient than creating array and testing whether it's empty.