# Can I use a list while forming it in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example, the below code

```
primeList = []
for val in range(2, num):
    if not any(val % i == 0 for i in primeList):
        primeList.append(val)
```

How can I turn this exact piece of code into list comprehension?

Comment: You should use a generator...

Comment: `primeList = [val for val in range(2, 20) if not any(val % i == 0 for i in primeList)]` wont work because `primeList` doesn't have the list associated with it until the comprehension is fully evaluated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093439/generating-a-list-of-prime-numbers-using-list-comprehension

Comment: I think the direct answers are "No" (to the question in your title) and "Not possible" (to the question at the end of your post)

Comment: Exactly I have guessed initially, that it should  not be possible, but what could be the closest mimic when i had nothing but list comprehension. ( this is not a development code, just my experiments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't, because the list doesn't exist as a Python object until the comprehension is finished iterating. You can't reference an object that doesn't exist. Honestly, I would just leave this as a `for` loop - list comprehensions aren't a magic bullet to replace all list-constructing loops.

However... you can get tricky and use a generator, which is only evaluated on demand. Combining this with the `extend()` method of a list, which adds elements to the list as it obtains them (in my tests, anyway), you can use the current contents of the list you're extending as you extend it.

```
# make sure to set `num`
plist = []
plist.extend(c for c in range(2, num) if not any(c % p == 0 for p in plist))
```

Fair warning: as far as I know, the fact that `extend()` adds elements to the list as it produces them is not part of the specification, so whether this bit of code works could be implementation-dependent. But I tested it in Python 2.7 and 3.4 and got a list of primes each time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `list comprehensions aren't a magic bullet to replace all list-constructing loops.` - that's the line I am looking for. I didn't think of generator earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you really really want to, you can create an identical copy of the list *within* the list comprehension and refer to that...

```
primeListCopy = []
primeList = [primeListCopy.append(val) or val for val in range(2, num)
                 if not any(val % i == 0 for i in primeListCopy)]
```

This uses the fact that `primeListCopy.append(val) or val` evaluates to `val`, because assignment to list returns `None` and `or` evaluates to the right side value.

This is definitely worse performance-wise than a simple `for-loop`.  I wrote this in response to OP's question "what could be the closest mimic when i had nothing but list comprehension. ( this is not a development code, just my experiments)"

That said, the additional work only *adds* O(n) of work so doesn't actually increase the algorithmic complexity of the loop.  It's conceivable (though not very likely) that the list comprehension optimization will make this faster than the original for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import math

def is_prime(x):
   if (x == 0 or x == 1 or x < 0):
      return False

   for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1):
      if (not (x % i)):
         return False 
   return True

def filter_primes(max):
   return [val for val in range(2, max) if is_prime(val)] 

def main():
   primes = filter_primes(20) 
   print(primes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

The code above starts with defining a function called `is_prime(x)` which returns True if `x` is a prime number, False otherwise. Then a function called `filter_primes(max)` uses is_prime with list comprehension to filter the prime numbers into an array that's returned. The maximum number of the range is specified via `max`. The main function just invokes the API to test it out.

EDIT:
But maybe I've misunderstood what you meant by "turn this exact piece of code into list comprehension". Depending on what you *really* want to do, using a generator is a great idea for dynamic purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I meant something else.